# Thread counter reading greater than zero after all threads have completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a thread counter on my program and it should hit 0 when all my threads have completed.  I started by having threads++ at the beginning of my worker and threads-- at the end but my counter was reading 145 after all threads completed.  So I put them right next to each other as shown below and it still is not reading 0, now it reads 8 after all threads have completed.  How is this even possible?  I am saving data from about 13000 mail messages to a sql server database.  Each message calls ProcessMailMessage once.

```
        int threads = 0;

        public bool ProcessMailMessage(byte[] mymsg, string username, string folder)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();

            bg.DoWork += (sss, res) => {
                
                threads++;
                threads--;
               // save some data to database

            };

            bg.RunWorkerAsync();

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: `threads++` is `threads = threads + 1`, which is not thread-safe (somewhat ironically). A thread-safe counter can be implemented with `lock` or `Interlocked.Increment`, assuming this setup is meaningful to begin with -- threaded database access is usually not such a hot idea, since the DB already knows how to parallelize individual queries, so it's often just something that covers up a flawed design that doesn't batch things up before processing.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. So the value can be different depending on which thread it is in at any moment.  I fixed it by moving threads++ just before RunWorkerAsync and then put threads-- inside the bg.RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: There is a lot of parsing going on (not shown here) so it does help to multi thread this function.  I am reading the mailbox backwards so I need a way write it back out in the correct order and it won't fit into memory so this is the best way I could think of.

Comment: Looks like it's about 10X faster to just write the files to a temp directory, so I guess I wont be adding them to a database after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by incrementing the counter before calling RunWorkerAsync() and decrementing in the RunWorkerComplete event

```
            bg.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, res) =>
            {
                threads--;
            };

            threads++;
            bg.RunWorkerAsync();
```